# How to hide function from the post author but not from logged_in user wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been searching for this but didn't find anything related to my requirements, I made a function in my theme for like dislike please see below.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
            get_like_dislike();
    }
```

How do I hide the function from the post author but not from the other logged in users in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code. This may help.

```
<?php
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  {
        get_like_dislike();
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but not from the current user I want to hide it from the post author

Comment: @YasirKhan: means you want to hide it from author posts page? author.php

Comment: its not author.php page but yes I want to hide it from the author posts but not from the others logged in users

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. The below code call **get_like_dislike** for logged in user but not for post author.

```
  global $current_user;
 if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID != $post->post_author)  {
        get_like_dislike();
    }
```